# How to avoid "Chi UTF-8 error" when dumping an etex from etex.src?

Tags: tex-core

"Chi error":

```
! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.18   \testengine ^^?
                      ^^?!\relax % That's Chi, a 2-byte UTF-8 sequence'
```

The error is triggered by

```
18  \testengine χ!\relax % That's Chi, a 2-byte UTF-8 sequence
```

in `dehypht-x-2019-04-04.tex` (windows 10 TexLive 2019 distribution).

Does eTeX need to be taught UTF-8 before it can handle this file? 
How to do this?

I just had the problem that the etex.src sometimes contained tabs instead of spaces.

Do I have another file problem with `dehypht-x-2019-04-04.tex` or is it an eTeX setup problem?

I generated eTeX with [web2js Convert TeX's pascal to javascript](https://github.com/kisonecat/web2js) .

```
 fmt_file = "*etex.src"
 library.setInput("\n" + fmt_file + " \\dump\n\n",
```

As you can see in the following log the "Chi" problem starts in the `dehypht-x-2019-04-04.tex` file:

```
This is e-TeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6 (INITEX)
**entering extended mode
(etex.src (plain.tex Preloading the plain format: codes, registers,
parameters, fonts, more fonts, macros, math definitions, output routines,
hyphenation (hyphen.tex [skipping from \patterns to end-of-file...]))
(etexdefs.lib Skipping module "grouptypes"; Loading module "interactionmodes";
Skipping module "nodetypes"; Skipping module "iftypes";) (language.def
(hyphen.tex) (dehypht-x-2019-04-04.tex
! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.18   \testengine ^^?
                      ^^?!\relax % That's Chi, a 2-byte UTF-8 sequence
? ! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.18   \testengine ^^?^^?
                         !\relax % That's Chi, a 2-byte UTF-8 sequence
? Runaway argument?
\relax \ifx \secondarg \empty \message {dehyph-exptl: using a \ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \testengine was complete.
<to be read again>
                   \par
l.132
.
.    
.
\relax \ifx \secondarg \empty \message {UTF-8 Hyphenation patt\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \testengine.
<inserted text>
                \par
\addlanguage ...uselanguage {#1}\input #2
                                          \if *#3*\else \input #3 \fi...
l.73 ...ntgreek}{loadhyph-grc.tex}{}{1}{1}

? (ibyhyph.tex Greek hyphenation patterns for Ibycus encoding, v3.0
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [pattern memory=8000].
l.615 a)2n1a'gku
```

Comment: Without `-ini` that can't work, but it should give a different error to the one you see. Something is clearly up with the IniTeX catcodes of your binary. Can you do ``etex -ini "\showthe\catcode`^^?"``?

Comment: Yes, that's for find the files, but eTeX should still report the full path

Comment: Well somehow it's in IniTeX mode (`\patterns` is allowed). You won't see the issue with the US patterns as they are not trying to do an engine test, but the other ones are (to support UTF-8 with pTeX in particular). Like I said, my guess is that the catcode set up is wrong: we need to see what ``\showthe\catcode`^^?`` gives.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96660/discussion-between-joseph-wright-and-carpediemkopi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is based on the ideas, hints and suggestions of David Carlisle, Joseph Wright and Marcel Krüger. They have solved the problem and I am just writing it down here.

It's an **character encoding** problem. `tex.web` reads one character per byte. However, *χ* (Chi) consists of 2 bytes: \xcf\x87 i.e. unicode code point U+03C7.

**How to teach `tex.web` to read UTF-8 input:**

`tex.sys`

```
%add the bigger codepage:

@x
for i:=0 to @'37 do xchr[i]:=' ';
for i:=@'177 to @'377 do xchr[i]:=' ';
@y
for i:=0 to @'37 do xchr[i]:=chr(i);
for i:=@'177 to @'377 do xchr[i]:=chr(i);
@z
```

Here you can find a more detailed instruction from Marcel Krüger how to use this 7 lines in a sys-file: [How to prepare a chg file, tie and tangle: tex.web tex.ch etex.ch and etex.sys to a new etex.web?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/501643/how-to-prepare-a-chg-file-tie-and-tangle-tex-web-tex-ch-etex-ch-and-etex-sys-t/501647#501647)

With this modification you can generate a system which can process *χ*.

**`chi_test.tex`**

```
\def\zz#1#2{[#1][#2]}
\immediate\write20{\zzχ..}
\end
```

**`output`**

```
This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (preloaded format=plain 1776.7.4)
**(chi_test.tex
[^^cf][^^87]..
 )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on chi_test.log.
```

Comment: @ShreevatsaR What exactly does `\def\zz#1#2{[#1][#2]}` means? I would expand this macro `zz`as follows: `\immediate\write20{[Chi_byte_1][Chi_byte2]..}` i.e. you just have to know here that chi is a container for 2 bytes which can be adressed bei #1 and #2?. You might as well think the first dot of `..` is #2.