# How to prepare a chg file, tie and tangle: tex.web tex.ch etex.ch and etex.sys to a new etex.web?

Tags: tex-core, e-tex, web

I need the following changes for tex.web in tex.ch. The section begins line 707. The actual change concerns the last two lines.

```
@ The ASCII code is ``standard'' only to a certain extent, since many
computer installations have found it advantageous to have ready access
to more than 94 printing characters. Appendix~C of {\sl The \TeX book\/}
gives a complete specification of the intended correspondence between
characters and \TeX's internal representation.
@:TeXbook}{\sl The \TeX book@>

If \TeX\ is being used
on a garden-variety \PASCAL\ for which only standard ASCII
codes will appear in the input and output files, it doesn't really matter
what codes are specified in |xchr[0..@'37]|, but the safest policy is to
blank everything out by using the code shown below.

However, other settings of |xchr| will make \TeX\ more friendly on
computers that have an extended character set, so that users can type things
like `\.^^Z' instead of `\.{\\ne}'. People with extended character sets can
assign codes arbitrarily, giving an |xchr| equivalent to whatever
characters the users of \TeX\ are allowed to have in their input files.
It is best to make the codes correspond to the intended interpretations as
shown in Appendix~C whenever possible; but this is not necessary. For
example, in countries with an alphabet of more than 26 letters, it is
usually best to map the additional letters into codes less than~@'40.
To get the most ``permissive'' character set, change |' '| on the
right of these assignment statements to |chr(i)|.
@^character set dependencies@>
@^system dependencies@>

@<Set init...@>=
for i:=0 to @'37 do xchr[i]:=chr(i);
for i:=@'177 to @'377 do xchr[i]:=chr(i);
```

**Change from:**

```
for i:=0 to @'37 do xchr[i]:=' ';
for i:=@'177 to @'377 do xchr[i]:=' ';
```

`tex.web` and `etex.ch` are the original files.
`etex.sys`comes from Marcel Krüger`s answer to my question: [Where can I find or how do I make the right etex.ch?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/500402/192681)

The change described here was suggested by David Carlisle to fix [How to avoid “Chi UTF-8 error” when dumping an etex from etex.src?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/501563/how-to-avoid-chi-utf-8-error-when-dumping-an-etex-from-etex-src?noredirect=1#comment1266771_501563).

I've tried, and I'm getting this result.

```
(Pardon me, but I think I spotted something wrong..)
```

**Here once again a thank you to all who have helped!**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend packing this change into the system change file for eTeX, `etex.sys`. It is the eTeX equivalent of TeX's `tex.ch` and using both is difficult because `tangle` only accepts one changefile.

If you read `etex_gen.tex` you will see that you are expected to include all `tex.ch` changes in `etex.sys`.

The alternative would be to apply a separate changefile `tex.ch` with the change using `tie`, but this would create a new `tex.web`(Bad, `tex.web` should not be changed according to it's license statement) or create a new `etex.web` (bad, `etex.web` should always be the original eTeX code). (You could invent a new name for your web file, but then you get chaos.)

So add, in `etex.sys`, the lines

```
@x [2.23] l.723 - Translate characters if desired, otherwise allow them all.
for i:=0 to @'37 do xchr[i]:=' ';
for i:=@'177 to @'377 do xchr[i]:=' ';
@y
{Initialize |xchr| to the identity mapping.}
for i:=0 to @'37 do xchr[i]:=chr(i);
for i:=@'177 to @'377 do xchr[i]:=chr(i);
@z
```

The trick is *where* to add these lines:
You have to make sure that the order of the blocks in `etex.sys` corresponds to the order in which the to-be changed lines appear in the original source. The `xchr` assignments come between the `@<Constants...@>=` and the `@d min_quarterword` block, so the changes have to added in the middle. The full system dependent  change file becomes: (I marked the insertion with `----> ... <----`)

```
eTeX compatible constants for web2js

@x
@<Constants...@>=
@!mem_max=30000; {greatest index in \TeX's internal |mem| array;
  must be strictly less than |max_halfword|;
  must be equal to |mem_top| in \.{INITEX}, otherwise |>=mem_top|}
@!mem_min=0; {smallest index in \TeX's internal |mem| array;
  must be |min_halfword| or more;
  must be equal to |mem_bot| in \.{INITEX}, otherwise |<=mem_bot|}
@!buf_size=500; {maximum number of characters simultaneously present in
  current lines of open files and in control sequences between
  \.{\\csname} and \.{\\endcsname}; must not exceed |max_halfword|}
@!error_line=72; {width of context lines on terminal error messages}
@!half_error_line=42; {width of first lines of contexts in terminal
  error messages; should be between 30 and |error_line-15|}
@!max_print_line=79; {width of longest text lines output; should be at least 60}
@!stack_size=200; {maximum number of simultaneous input sources}
@!max_in_open=6; {maximum number of input files and error insertions that
  can be going on simultaneously}
@!font_max=75; {maximum internal font number; must not exceed |max_quarterword|
  and must be at most |font_base+256|}
@!font_mem_size=20000; {number of words of |font_info| for all fonts}
@!param_size=60; {maximum number of simultaneous macro parameters}
@!nest_size=40; {maximum number of semantic levels simultaneously active}
@!max_strings=3000; {maximum number of strings; must not exceed |max_halfword|}
@!string_vacancies=8000; {the minimum number of characters that should be
  available for the user's control sequences and font names,
  after \TeX's own error messages are stored}
@!pool_size=32000; {maximum number of characters in strings, including all
  error messages and help texts, and the names of all fonts and
  control sequences; must exceed |string_vacancies| by the total
  length of \TeX's own strings, which is currently about 23000}
@!save_size=600; {space for saving values outside of current group; must be
  at most |max_halfword|}
@!trie_size=8000; {space for hyphenation patterns; should be larger for
  \.{INITEX} than it is in production versions of \TeX}
@!trie_op_size=500; {space for ``opcodes'' in the hyphenation patterns}
@!dvi_buf_size=800; {size of the output buffer; must be a multiple of 8}
@!file_name_size=40; {file names shouldn't be longer than this}
@!pool_name='TeXformats:TEX.POOL                     ';
  {string of length |file_name_size|; tells where the string pool appears}
@.TeXformats@>

@ Like the preceding parameters, the following quantities can be changed
at compile time to extend or reduce \TeX's capacity. But if they are changed,
it is necessary to rerun the initialization program \.{INITEX}
@.INITEX@>
to generate new tables for the production \TeX\ program.
One can't simply make helter-skelter changes to the following constants,
since certain rather complex initialization
numbers are computed from them. They are defined here using
\.{WEB} macros, instead of being put into \PASCAL's |const| list, in order to
emphasize this distinction.

@d mem_bot=0 {smallest index in the |mem| array dumped by \.{INITEX};
  must not be less than |mem_min|}
@d mem_top==30000 {largest index in the |mem| array dumped by \.{INITEX};
  must be substantially larger than |mem_bot|
  and not greater than |mem_max|}
@y
@<Constants...@>=
@!mem_max=200000; {greatest index in \TeX's internal |mem| array;
  must be strictly less than |max_halfword|;
  must be equal to |mem_top| in \.{INITEX}, otherwise |>=mem_top|}
@!mem_min=0; {smallest index in \TeX's internal |mem| array;
  must be |min_halfword| or more;
  must be equal to |mem_bot| in \.{INITEX}, otherwise |<=mem_bot|}
@!buf_size=5000; {maximum number of characters simultaneously present in
  current lines of open files and in control sequences between
  \.{\\csname} and \.{\\endcsname}; must not exceed |max_halfword|}
@!error_line=72; {width of context lines on terminal error messages}
@!half_error_line=42; {width of first lines of contexts in terminal
  error messages; should be between 30 and |error_line-15|}
@!max_print_line=79; {width of longest text lines output; should be at least 60}
@!stack_size=1000; {maximum number of simultaneous input sources}
@!max_in_open=6; {maximum number of input files and error insertions that
  can be going on simultaneously}
@!font_max=75; {maximum internal font number; must not exceed |max_quarterword|
  and must be at most |font_base+256|}
@!font_mem_size=20000; {number of words of |font_info| for all fonts}
@!param_size=60; {maximum number of simultaneous macro parameters}
@!nest_size=40; {maximum number of semantic levels simultaneously active}
@!max_strings=60000; {maximum number of strings; must not exceed |max_halfword|}
@!string_vacancies=300000; {the minimum number of characters that should be
  available for the user's control sequences and font names,
  after \TeX's own error messages are stored}
@!pool_size=350000; {maximum number of characters in strings, including all
  error messages and help texts, and the names of all fonts and
  control sequences; must exceed |string_vacancies| by the total
  length of \TeX's own strings, which is currently about 23000}
@!save_size=600; {space for saving values outside of current group; must be
  at most |max_halfword|}
@!trie_size=8000; {space for hyphenation patterns; should be larger for
  \.{INITEX} than it is in production versions of \TeX}
@!trie_op_size=500; {space for ``opcodes'' in the hyphenation patterns}
@!dvi_buf_size=800; {size of the output buffer; must be a multiple of 8}
@!file_name_size=40; {file names shouldn't be longer than this}
@!pool_name='TeXformats:TEX.POOL                     ';
  {string of length |file_name_size|; tells where the string pool appears}
@.TeXformats@>

@ Like the preceding parameters, the following quantities can be changed
at compile time to extend or reduce \TeX's capacity. But if they are changed,
it is necessary to rerun the initialization program \.{INITEX}
@.INITEX@>
to generate new tables for the production \TeX\ program.
One can't simply make helter-skelter changes to the following constants,
since certain rather complex initialization
numbers are computed from them. They are defined here using
\.{WEB} macros, instead of being put into \PASCAL's |const| list, in order to
emphasize this distinction.

@d mem_bot=0 {smallest index in the |mem| array dumped by \.{INITEX};
  must not be less than |mem_min|}
@d mem_top==200000 {largest index in the |mem| array dumped by \.{INITEX};
  must be substantially larger than |mem_bot|
  and not greater than |mem_max|}
@z

----> Here we add the bigger codepage: <----

@x
for i:=0 to @'37 do xchr[i]:=' ';
for i:=@'177 to @'377 do xchr[i]:=' ';
@y
for i:=0 to @'37 do xchr[i]:=chr(i);
for i:=@'177 to @'377 do xchr[i]:=chr(i);
@z

----> End of insertion <----

@x
@d min_quarterword=0 {smallest allowable value in a |quarterword|}
@d max_quarterword=255 {largest allowable value in a |quarterword|}
@d min_halfword==0 {smallest allowable value in a |halfword|}
@d max_halfword==65535 {largest allowable value in a |halfword|}
@y
@d min_quarterword=0 {smallest allowable value in a |quarterword|}
@d max_quarterword=255 {largest allowable value in a |quarterword|}
@d min_halfword==0 {smallest allowable value in a |halfword|}
@d max_halfword==16777215 {largest allowable value in a |halfword|}
@z
```

Then just use the usual dance:

```
tie -m etex.web tex.web etex.ch
tangle -underline etex.web etex.sys
```