# Kpathsee looking for file "babel-xelatex.cfg"

Tags: xetex, babel, hyphenation, compilation-error, format-files

Im working on compiling a format file using a XeLaTeX engine and It is trying to fetch a file babel-xelatex.cfg which is not found anywhere in MacTeX.

It seems that upon initialisation "hyphen.cfg" and "xebabel.def" are somehow resolving the expression "openin1 = babel-\bbl@format.cfg" as openin1 = babel-xelatex.cfg? Atleast that is my guess.

Has anyone worked with these kind of issues or seen similar?

Comment: what is your actual error? the file doesn't exist by default but you can make it for local config. The line you show is followed (in `babel.def` )by `\ifeof1`  that is, it is testing if the file exists.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: sorry `hyphen.cfg` not `babel.def`

Comment: It makes good sense, thanks. So if the file doesn't exist, it should be able to handle this successfully by fetching a file that might exist? Is it some kind of support for older engines, this "babel-xelatex.cfg" file which it is looking for?

Comment: Also, let me try to elaborate what i have involved myself in:
I have this older xelatex engine compiled into Webassembly. It needs a format-file to compile .tex files into .pdf/.dvi files. I dont have such format-file so I tried using "xelatex.fmt" from MacTex without any success. Therefore im now using it to compile a format file in the belief that this format file would be compatible with the older XeLateX engine and usable for compiling .tex files into .pdf/.dvi files.
Im a new to this, so i excuse any confusions

Comment: I might have solved that particular issue in my own server, which was tricking kpathsee to think that the file actually existed..

Comment: for that file if the file doesn't exist it simply does nothing it is like `\InputIfFileExists{somefile}` but if that test is breaking while making the format it would seem all file access in your webasssembly  xetex is suspect. It should not genetrate any error it is simply testing if the file is end-of-file on opening, which means it doesn't exist.  (it doesn't matter but it's kpathsea short for k's path search) not see)  I am not sure what answer can be given to the question as written other than to say the file is not expected to exist and the test for it should not cause any error.

Comment: Knowing what \ifeof1 means led me to the solution. It successfully compiles now, thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/502962/example-of-babel-bblformat-cfg-i-e-babel-cfg-typical-content-where-do