# How to create docker environment for Pascal to WASM compiler web2js?

Tags: tex-core, web, initex

### What is web2js?

> This is a Pascal compiler that targets WebAssembly, designed specifically to compile TeX so it can be run inside the browser. More specifically, this repository includes a TeX engine called jsTeX which is like LuaTeX but instead of embedding Lua it embeds JavaScript.

Specifically, web2js produce core.dump and tex.wasm by [this step](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/499669/how-to-make-an-e-tex-webassembly-with-jim-fowlers-web-tex-pascal-to-wasm-compil) in `Makefile`.

### Question

[`web2js`](https://github.com/kisonecat/web2js) has some dependencies to produce `core.dump`. It is hard to setup the local environment, therefore I want the Docker environment.

```
FROM adnrv/texlive:full 

# Update tex packages
RUN tlmgr update --self --all

ARG WORKDIR=/usr/var
WORKDIR ${WORKDIR}

# Install apt pacakges
RUN apt update && apt install -y \
  build-essential \
  cmake \
  git \
  libkpathsea-dev \
  python3-pip

# Install npm and node
ARG NODE_MAJOR_VERSION=14
ARG NODE_MINOR_VERSION=14.18.1
RUN wget https://deb.nodesource.com/node_${NODE_MAJOR_VERSION}.x/pool/main/n/nodejs/nodejs_${NODE_MINOR_VERSION}-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb \
  && apt install ./nodejs_${NODE_MINOR_VERSION}-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb \
  && rm nodejs_${NODE_MINOR_VERSION}-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb

# Install binaryen
ARG BINARYEN_VERSION=91
RUN wget https://github.com/WebAssembly/binaryen/archive/refs/tags/version_${BINARYEN_VERSION}.tar.gz \
  && tar -zxf version_${BINARYEN_VERSION}.tar.gz \
  && cd binaryen-version_${BINARYEN_VERSION} \
  && cmake . && make \
  && make install \
  && cd ../ && rm -rf binaryen-version_${BINARYEN_VERSION} version_${BINARYEN_VERSION}.tar.gz

# Install node packages
COPY package.json ${WORKDIR}/
RUN npm install

# Build
COPY . ${WORKDIR}/

# Produce tex.wasm and core.dump
RUN make core.dump

# Compile sampleLatex.tex by running
# RUN node tex.js sample/sampleLatex
```

This is my `Dockerfile` but `! I can't read TEX.POOL.` error has occurred at `node initex.js`.

The following is that log.

```
! I can't read TEX.POOL.
[Object: null prototype] {
  '0': Memory [WebAssembly.Memory] {},
  getStackPointer: [Function: 20],
  setStackPointer: [Function: 21],
  main: [Function: 385],
  asyncify_start_unwind: [Function: 386],
  asyncify_stop_unwind: [Function: 387],
  asyncify_start_rewind: [Function: 388],
  asyncify_stop_rewind: [Function: 387]
}
! I can't read TEX.POOL.
```

This message is sent out from the source file but I don't know what is needed or wrong.
`tex.pool` file is certainly exist by `tangle`. How can I fix it?